# Statement from visuddhimagga regarding mental and material body

Tags: visuddhimagga

I found this statement in the Visuddhimagga;

> They cannot come to be by their own strength,
>   Or yet maintain themselves by their own strength;
>   Relying for support on other states,
>   Weak in themselves, and formed, they come to be; [597]
>   They come to be with others as condition.
>   They are aroused by others as their objects,
>   They are produced by object and condition,
>   And each by something other than itself.
>   And just as men depend upon
>   A boat for traversing the sea.
>   So does the mental body need
>   The matter-body for occurrence.
>   And as the boat depends upon
>   The men for traversing the sea.
>   So does the matter-body need
>   The mental body for occurrence.
>   Depending each upon the other
>   The boat and men go on the sea.
>   And so do mind and matter both
>   Depend the one upon the other.

The above statement seems to confirm that mind doesn't have occurrence without material body, and vise versa. Both factors are interdependent and seemingly co-exists.

But, once, I heard that one's mind does't end at death of material body: how can that match with the above statement in the Visuddhimagga?

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide a reference to the statement.

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf

Comment: Do you want to give a reference for the second statement as well, "I heard that one's mind does't end at death of material body"?

Answer (score 1):

You said: *The above statement seems to confirm that mind doesn't have occurrence without material body, and vise versa. Both factors are interdependent and seemingly co-exist.*

Correct. In my (personal) understanding of Buddhist teaching, speaking in modern terms, Mind is Information. Information needs Media to carry it. And Media is Energy that takes certain Form due to the shaping influence of Causes and Conditions carrying Information. So Energy, Matter, and Information are aspects of the same underlying "ground of all".

*"But, once, I heard that **one's mind** does't end at death of material body: how can that match with the above statement"?*

In my (personal) understanding of Buddhist teaching, there is no such thing as "one's mind" - it's a mistake to think that way. Mind is not an entity, it's an aspect. Mind is like wind that goes in and out, like breath. Mind is information that is all around us, moving like wind.

I know this sounds like Materialism but it's not. With this interpretation we are not declaring the primacy of Matter. What I am saying is that "regular" Information and Energy is what the ancients called "spirit". This is what animates Matter. As a matter of fact, Matter, if you look at it very closely (at the level of electrons), is empty. It is only a shape that Energy takes.

This may also sound like Pantheism, as in, we are declaring that Mind is a global aspect of everything and that it is God. To this I respond that sure Mind is a global aspect of everything - but so is Energy, so is Space/Time - but we do not pray to Space/Time and declare it our God? Why should we identify Mind as God?

This may also sound like Nondualism, as in "I am this global Mind, and this global Mind is speaking through me now" and "The highest realization is to awake to unity with this global Mind" - but that would be conceit and self-identification, wouldn't it? Instead, as Buddha taught, the highest realization is to be free from conceit, free from such thoughts, and free from self-identification.

My Zen Master said: "operate mind, don't let mind operate you" and "you bless god, not 'god bless you'". This means we must understand how Information works, how Universe works, and how Mind works. Once we understand how it works, we should master it. When we master Mind, we can pick our interpretation of reality. When we can pick our interpretation of reality, we can shape our reality. When we can shape our reality, we are free.

Comment: @AV; you have beautifully created this answer using your deep knowledge in Buddhism and science. I am confused with some of your statements. E.g- your description of "mind is information", When you consider what is information in here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/information you will realize why i am confused and instead i suggest "mind create information with help of matter". secondly yes i accept mention "Once's mind" as a mistake as it create issue if self. Also when i analyze your answer i seem you have created your own conceptualize model for mind&body question.

Comment: Why should we identify Mind as God? yes i feel what you are trying to say. mind as god- because mind is the creator of all the concepts,ideologies,words and informations(with the assistance of matter,physical world or any other suitable word)  and in above sense your statement is correct but it unnecessary because "almighty god concept" is outdated. But your "mind" and "almighty god" marriage is so creative and you have capacity to create it as you have roots in concept of  almighty god(i feel your base on Christianity,perfectly gained knowledge in Buddhist teaching and science. I say your...

Comment: mind is extremely beautiful and creative. In same manner I can also create different model for metaphysical questions. E.g 1. I can say all the stars in universe possesses consciousness which we don't have any interface to communicate. 2. we are in illusion of mechanical cyber space which is controlled by extraterrestrials with extremely higher technology. etc....But what is important is what Buddha's genuine and ultimate message to humans and what is the ultimate truth of reality or nature.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this question is that you assume that the present body is the only matter available for the mind to hold on to. The whole universe is full of matter that is conducive to the continuation of the mental stream.

There are 4 ways for the mental stream to find a new body. Namely, egg-born beings (andaja), womb-born beings (jalabuja), moisture-born beings (samsedaja), and beings having spontaneous births (opapatika).

Comment: I am not assuming and it's not the "present"body. I just stick to the statement  in Visuddhimagga.So does the mental body need The matter-body for occurrence.The whole universe is full of matter that is conducive to the continuation of the mental stream.- yes but those materials in universe must be organized in certain way so called "body" to sustain "mind" and "continuation of the mental stream" is problematic. what is that unknown "continuation" and can you explain it little further.

Comment: Also continuation of "mental stream" which travel to find the new body is closer to atman or soul. Now you will respond that there is mental stream does't possesses "self". but still you have stated phenomena of continuation of such specific thing as "mental stream" which you unable to define what is it seemingly mysterious.

Comment: Mental stream is a conceptual term. In reality it is just thought moments appearing one after the other. There's nothing peresisting. They all arise and die instantaneously. When you were born, the suitable material conditions for the consciousness to arise were made available by the union of your mother and father. This is why the Buddha told to treat your parents as your creator. Not some mysterious God. That is just one form of birth. There are 3 more. When you die this time, you will be born again in one of those 4 ways.

Comment: I get what you are trying to convey. I am not denying and I feel your comment attempt to reach materialistic way. how ever now you have used words such as mental stream(mind),consciousness, and thoughts. can you distinguish above three words in simple manner.

Comment: When you die this time, you will be born again in one of those 4 ways.- If you convert you to I, you mean when I die, I will be born again. This is nothing more than view of soul or atman. conituation of I, Isn't it?

Comment: Think of it as the computer screen in front of you. You see it as continuously on. But in reality it is not. It just appears continuously on because the screen is refreshing many times within a second. In the same way continuous thoughts appear like a mental stream or gives the illusion of a persisting mind because they appear in quick succession.

Comment: "you will be born again" is a conceptual statement.  What it means in reality is that after the last thought moment of this life ends, a new thought moment will arise in another place depending on the karma that comes forward to give birth.

Comment: This is explained at the very beginning of Paticca Samuppada

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75180/discussion-between-sankha-kulathantille-and-danuka-shewantha).